# Cannot append style to div using veriable

Tags: javascript, html, css, classname

I can append a style inline when using a string like so

```
element.style.width='100px';
```

However it does not append if i use a variable like so

```
    //get ID of clicked elemnt
    var divId = cssPath(e.target).substring(1);
    var tagetDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    var targetWidth = tagetDiv.clientWidth;

    var overlayDiv = document.createElement('div');
    overlayDiv.className = 'bsOverlay';
    overlayDiv.style.width=targetWidth;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clientWidth` is a number.

The CSS `width` property requires a unit (typically `px`).

You need to concatenate it:

`overlayDiv.style.width = targetWidth + 'px';`